# Issue converting JavaScript code to CoffeeScript and global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am learning Coffeescript and trying to convert the following JavaScript code to Coffescript and (I think) I am almost there.  Mainly, I am having an issue with making the `timer` and `popover_parent` variables global:

```
$('.some_element').popover(
  {
    delay: { show: 350, hide: 100 }       
  }
);
var timer,
    popover_parent;
function hidePopover(elem) {
    $(elem).popover('hide');
}
$('.some_element').hover(
    function() {
      var self = this;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      $('.popover').hide(); //Hide any open popovers on other elements.
      popover_parent = self
      $(self).popover('show');            
    }, 
    function() {
      var self = this;
      timer = setTimeout(function(){hidePopover(self)},300);                 
});
$('.popover').on({
  mouseover: function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    var self = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){hidePopover(popover_parent)},300); 
  }
});
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$ ->
  $('.some_element')
    .popover ->
      delay: {show:350, hide: 100}
$ ->
  hidePopover = (elem) ->
    $(elem).popover('hide')

  $('.some_element').hover(
    ->
      self = $(this)
      clearTimeout(timer)
      $('.popover').hide()
      popover_parent = self
      $(self).popover('show')
    ->
      self = $(this)
      timer = setTimeout(
        ->
          hidePopover(self) 300
      )
  )

$ ->
  $(document).on({
    mouseover: ->
      clearTimeout(timer)
    mouseleave: ->
      timer = setTimeout(
        ->
          hidePopover(popover_parent) 300
      )
  })
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest not using CoffeeScript at all. It's not making your code noticeably shorter or more readable.

Comment: [this](http://js2coffee.org/) might help

Comment: From Blazemonger's comment, I should point out that there are two distinct camps on JS/CS: people that think CS dilutes the JS community with a "designer" language and people that think CS allows code to be more concise and readable. If you google "coffeescript vs javascript" you will see this internet-wide flame war in all its glory.

Comment: Converting javascript to coffeescript is like converting c++ to java. Will lead to ugly code imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you knew about http://js2coffee.org, but if it works with your code it's a really quick way to learn how to convert Javascript to Coffeescript. I used it a lot when getting started with coffee.

It also does compilation of coffee to js, of course.